# Text shatters after pressing up arrow and changing bash prompt

Tags: bash, text, prompt

So I recently decided to change my bash prompt and I have a problem. After pressing up arrow a few times so I don't have to write the command I used like a minute ago the command suddenly breaks the whole prompt and the characters are randomly shattered.

I added this to my bash profile:

```
export PS1="[\e[32m]\u[\e[m]@[\e[32m]\s[\e[m]-[\e[32m]\W[\e[m] >> "
```

After pressing the up arrow like two or three times, the characters become totally scrambled like this:

```
do nano ~/.bash_profile-[]Downloads[] >> source ~/.bash_profile  
pwd                                                      sudo nano 
~/.bash_profile
```

Guys please help me, it's really annoying. Thanks.

Comment: You need `\[...\]` around non-printing characters, not `[...]`. That's why you have a bunch of `[]` scattered throughout your prompt.

Comment: That isn't the problem. I know about the `[]` symbols. The problem is, whenever I press up arrow to list through previous commands the text mixes up and looks like randomly generated text from the characters entered before.

Comment: Yes, because `bash` doesn't know how long your prompt really is, because you *aren't* using the `\[...\]` to properly hide the ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks! With ur help I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered in comments. Here is the answer:

> You need \[...\] around non-printing characters, not [...]. That's why you have a bunch of [] scattered throughout your prompt.

Thanks